# numpy array slicing with arbitrary dimension

Tags: python, numpy, dimension

Say I create an array of arbitrary dimension (n).

```
#assign the dimension

>>> n=22

#create the numpy array

>>> TheArray=zeros([2]*n)

>>> shape(TheArray)

(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Have some code (skipped in this example) to populate the values of the array.

Now, try to access some values of the array

```
>>> TheArray[0:2,0:2,0:2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

How to make the `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` part of the syntax generalized to n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use [numpy.s_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html):

```
In [55]: m = arange(2**6).reshape([2]*6)

In [56]: m.shape
Out[56]: (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

In [57]: m[:2,:2,:2,0,0,0]
Out[57]: 
array([[[ 0,  8],
        [16, 24]],

       [[32, 40],
        [48, 56]]])

In [58]: m[s_[:2, :2, :2] + (0,)*(n-3)]
Out[58]: 
array([[[ 0,  8],
        [16, 24]],

       [[32, 40],
        [48, 56]]])
```

And I guess you could get rid of the hardcoded -3..

```
In [69]: m[(s_[:2, :2, :2] + (0,)*m.ndim)[:m.ndim]]
Out[69]: 
array([[[ 0,  8],
        [16, 24]],

       [[32, 40],
        [48, 56]]])
```

but to be honest, I'd probably just wrap this up in a function if I needed it.

Comment: thanks. the python and numpy documentation was not clear enough to lead me to this conclusion, but after your example was provided,  I was able to piece together the python and numpy documentation to understand this.